# How to add obj file to C++ project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, unit-testing

This is about adding .obj file to C++ Win32 project using project properties.
There are multiple references across the web about adding the path to Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies, but that doesn't work.

Usually it is mentioned in connection with unit tests, but it behaves the same with stripped-down console project. Tried Visual Studios 2019 and 2008. .obj file contains a class with a single public method. No external dependencies.

I can add it directly to the project (like another .cpp file), but for some reason all sources advise using project properties. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what this Question is about but I suppose you  want to kind of link a object code (.obj) to your build.

In C++ we use library(.lib or .a) as an external dependencies which is nothing but collection of many object files for a particular operation. There could be one also. We use many object files in library just to make things simple otherwise we can choose to use only one.

**Library vs object file**

Object file is for Translational Unit that's it is generated when we compile without linking. Library is for complete project that contains many object file linked with each other. A object file can be used as Library but that's not appropriate.

Linking a library to build is equivalent to link all its object code. So, You can choose to link object code manually from command line. There is no way you can link a object code from property page. I don't know how you got object code without source but There's a way you can add object code indirectly.

Simply make your object code a library. To do that, Open Developers Command Prompt (You can also add toolset directory to PATH). Then pass this command

```
lib /out:library.lib object.obj
```

Now add library.lib to your project from properties page.

Comment: I know about lib files, the question is not about that. And, to add .obj file, all you have to do, is to drop it in the Solution Explorer pane. The question is, why on Earth everybody is advising to use project properties, which obviously doesn't work. Take, for example, this site (one of many): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2019. It plainly tells, how to "Link to object or library files". Do I miss some setting??